# How can i add data in dropzone like uploadify?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, file-upload

I used dropzone.js for uploading file. But, I want to send ProductID from .aspx file to .ashx file.

Uploadify has scriptData for that. In dropzone, What should i use to do that ?

For example:
in Uploadify:

```
var ProductID = $('#ctl00_contentside_tempProductID').val();

            $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                'uploader': 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                'script': 'uploadify/UrunResimUpload.ashx',
                'scriptData': { 'id': ProductID },
                'buttonText': 'Bul / Yolla',
                'cancelImg': 'uploadify/cancel.png',
                'folder': 'upl',
                'multi': true,
                'auto': true,
                'method': 'post',
                'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png',
                'onComplete': function (event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {...}
```

in Dropzone :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
                //Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = false;
                 $("#myAwesomeDropzone").dropzone({
                     uploadMultiple: true,
                     autoProcessQueue: true,
                    paramName: "file", 
                    maxFilesize: 20000, // MB
                    parallelUploads: 10,
                    clickable: true,
                     maxFiles: 10,
                     autoProcessQueue: true,
                    url : "Scripts/dropzone/ProductFileUpload.ashx"
                });

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `params` property:

```
$("#myAwesomeDropzone").dropzone({
  params: { id: ProductID },
```